# Creating an instance of an object with an optional list type attribute

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

I have a class (Cat) that has an optional attribute (alias). The alias attribute is an empty list if it's not provided at instance creation. That works fine, I can create instances of the Cat object and append strings to the alias. If I create an instance of the Cat object and provide only a single value for the attribute alias then when I try to append to it I get an error
 `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`.

I've tried several ways to have `def __init__` append the single value but none of those seem to work.

I can create the object instance and then append the single value to the attribute but I feel like I don't understand what I'm doing so I'd like to explore how this should work.

```
class Cat(): 
    """A simple attempt to model a cat."""
    def __init__(self, name, alias=[], age=None):
        """Initialize name and age attributes."""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.alias = alias

# testing default value -- my_cat    
my_cat = Cat('Nat')

# appending to the alias
my_cat.alias.append('Monster')

print (my_cat.name, " ", my_cat.alias)

# prints: Nat   ['Monster']

#testing with inital value -- alley_cat
alley_cat = Cat('Smelly Cat', 'smelly', 6)

##& we've set a value to alias at object creation, see if that forces alias to a string rather than a list.
alley_cat.alias.append('Stinker')

# throws error: 
    # alley_cat.alias.append('Stinker')
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

print (alley_cat.Name, " ", alley_cat.alias)
```

---

Comment: When you provide the constructor with parameters, then those parameters will be used instead of any defaults. So the `string` `'smelly'` will be assigned to `self.alias`. Then its a string. Perhaps you meant: `Cat('Smelly Cat', ['smelly'], 6)`?

Comment: btw see this question about [default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @quamrana thanks for that tip! I'm actually getting the value from a variable and what I'll have to do  is use a temp list to add the single value to in order to create the object. It makes more sense now that I think about passing a string, it's turning the attribute to a string.

Comment: It doesn’t matter where the value comes from, you can turn it into a single element list directly: Cat('Smelly Cat', [ var ], 6)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the alias parameter in the `__init__` function and wrap it in a list if it is not one:

```
if not isinstance(alias, list):
    self.alias = [alias]
else:
    self.alias = alias
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that can take the `alias` arg as a string and put it into a list on instantiation.  The `append_alias` method allows you to add values to the `alias` list. You can also supply multiple alias' in the form of a single string with comma separated values:

```
class Cat():

    def __init__(self, name, alias=None, age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

        if alias is None:
            self.alias = []
        else:
            self.alias = [a.lstrip().rstrip() for a in alias.split(',')]

    def append_alias(self, add_alias):

        [self.alias.append(a.lstrip().rstrip())
         for a in add_alias.split(',')]

my_cat = Cat('cats_name', 'alias1')

my_cat.alias
Output:
['alias1']

my_cat.append_alias('alias2, alias3')

my_cat.alias
Output:
['alias1', 'alias2', 'alias3']

my_cat.name
Output:
'cats_name'
```